# mysql max condition use in where clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MAX(r.endTime) as maxETime,r.vehicleId,v.emixis_id
FROM reservation r , vehicle v 
WHERE r.vehicleId = v.vehicleId AND 
r.workingDay = CURRENT_DATE() AND 
r.isNote=0 AND 
r.isDeleted=0 AND 
r.status NOT IN("cancelled") AND 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H:%i:%s') > DATE_SUB(MAX(r.endTime), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
GROUP BY r.vehicleId;
```

This is my code, what want to do is get `MAX(r.endTime)` value in to `DATE_SUB`.  `MAX` not working with where condition, is there way to do this kind of thing ? I tried with `@var:=MAX(r.endTime)` and set it inside `DATE_SUB`, but `@var` always store last row's value.

Comment: Output column cannot be used in WHERE, but can be used in HAVING. Move.

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. Join us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(r.`endTime`) as `maxETime`,r.`vehicleId`,v.`emixis_id`
FROM `reservation` r , `vehicle` v 
WHERE r.`vehicleId` = v.`vehicleId` AND 
r.`workingDay` = CURRENT_DATE() AND 
r.`isNote`=0 AND 
r.`isDeleted`=0 AND 
r.`status` NOT IN("cancelled")
GROUP BY r.`vehicleId` 
HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H:%i:%s') > DATE_ADD(MAX(r.`endTime`),     INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```